# Proof that variance-covariance matrix of var(b|X) - var(b*|X) is positive-semidefinite

Tags: least-squares, linear, covariance-matrix, cholesky-decomposition

I'm having trouble finding the proof to show that the variance-covariance matrix of var (b|X) - var (b*|X) is positive-semidefinite.

OLS estimator =
[image]

GLS estimator =
[image]

Hint:
Note that A is the Cholesky factor of **var(b|X) - var(b*|X)** given by
[image] where C is Cholesky factor of [image]

Assume that [image] is true and show that [image] implies [image]

Comment: *All* var-cov matrices are positive semidefinite, because that's equivalent to stating that all variances are non-negative (which is obvious, because the variance is the expectation of a non-negative random variable).  Please clarify, then, what kind of "interpretation" you might be looking for.